# Why is my Spring Boot with Scala not running CommandLineUtil

Tags: spring, spring-boot, scala

I have the following basic Spring Boot app in scala...

```
import org.slf4j.{Logger, LoggerFactory}
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication
import org.springframework.boot.{CommandLineRunner, SpringApplication}

@SpringBootApplication
class TestCompanyApp{

}

object TestCompany extends CommandLineRunner{
  val logger:Logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(classOf[TestCompanyApp])
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    logger.error("Starting....")
    SpringApplication run classOf[TestCompanyApp]
  }
  override def run(args: String*): Unit = {
    logger.error("Worked!")
  }
}
```

When I run this with `mvn spring-boot:run` I see the Starting but not the worked. Why is the work not getting called?

Comment: The `TestCompany` isn't anything? It only implements an interface. It isn't marked as a spring `@Component` so nothing will be detected.

Comment: I tried (at)Component
object TestCompany but it doesn't work still. FTR the equivalent runs in Java so I don't think I need another (at)Component but I am not 100%

Comment: I doubt they are equivalent there is probably some `@Bean` or `@Component` that you don't have in your scala version.

Comment: Can you share the equivalent Java code working?

Comment: Should be posted as the answer @GaëlJ

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I am a Scala newbie this does seem to work...

```
@SpringBootApplication
class TestCompanyApp extends CommandLineRunner{
  override def run(args: String*): Unit = {
    logger.error("Worked!")
  }
}

object TestCompany{
  val logger:Logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(classOf[TestCompanyApp])
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    logger.error("Starting....")
    SpringApplication run classOf[TestCompanyApp]
  }
}
```